# Flex - DataGrid - text field with carriage returns causing grid rows to grow vertically, how to prevent?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder

I have a flex (flash builder 4.6) DataGrid.   One of the columns is a notes field.   If there are carriage returns (multiple lines of text) in the field, and the row is the first row in the grid, it causes all the rows in the grid to grow vertically (become taller)!    How can I prevent this so it simply cuts off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the property [`variableRowHeight`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#variableRowHeight)
also related to that will be [`rowHeight`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#rowHeight)

I don't have 4.6 to test this out, but if you are ok with setting a fixed size for the rowHeight of all rows, this should work for you.

Let me know if you have questions.